# Update nested array in reducer using object.assign

Tags: reactjs

I have a switch case that updates an item in my `achievements` array, how can I have a similar switch case for `DELETE_ACHIEVEMENT` that removes the text from the array?

```
case ADD_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, item, {
            achievements: [
            ...item.achievements,
            action.text,
            ]
          });
      }

    return item;
});

case REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(item => {
      if (item.id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, item, {
          // check text is in array and delete?
            achievements: [
            ...item.achievements,
            action.text,
            ]
          });
      }

    return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use Array.prototype.filter() to check current achivements and return elements different to action.text:

```
case REMOVE_ACHIEVEMENT:
      return state.map(item => {
          if (item.id === action.id) {
              return Object.assign({}, item, {
                achievements: [
                ...item.achievements.filter(achievement => achievement !== action.text)
                ]
              });
          }

        return item;
    });
```